# Using Custom view.phtml into Magento using local.xml

Tags: html, magento

I've been looking and I can't find the exact answer to my question. I've created a custom view.phtml file on my site and stored it in my "customchanges" folder located at /app/design/frontend/argento/default/template/customchanges/catalog/product/view.phtml

I've also created a local.xml file which I store in /app/design/frontend/argento/default/layout/local.xml

My code in my local.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default> 
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>customchanges/catalog/product/view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

But when I refresh the page (and use hints) I still get the default page. Please could someone help?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, if it's helpful here's the solution:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>customchanges/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
           </action>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```